# How do i pass php variable to .js file to create function Chart

Tags: javascript, php, html

i done create my chart but i dont know how to pass it, i already try use ?php  but its not working.. and i already define in head like below, but when i try to pass it. the php file returning "''" like function tooltips title

```
<script src="includes/templates/chart.js"></script>
```

chart.js

```
window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ['08:00'] , //Jamnya
                datasets: [{
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(85, 212, 226, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: '#55d4e2',
                    label: '<?php echo $dtDateChart1; ?>' ,
                    data: [600],
                    fill: true,
                    pointRadius: 5,
                    pointHoverRadius: 10,
                    showLine: true
                }]
            }, options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Total Online Today',
                    position: 'top',
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontStyle: 'bold'
                },
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                elements: {
                    point: {
                        pointStyle: 'circle'
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'TIME'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            major: {
                                fontStyle: 'bold',
                                fontColor: '#FF0000'
                            }
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'TOTAL ONLINE'
                        }
                    }]
                },
                tooltips:{
                    callbacks: {
                        title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                          return '<?php echo $dtDateChart1; ?>' +data['labels'][tooltipItem[0]['index']];
                        },
                        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                          return 'TOTAL : '+data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']]+'';
                        },
                    },
                    titleFontSize: 15,
                    bodyFontSize: 15,
                    displayColors: false
                }
            }
        }
     );

     return myChart;

}
```

in my php file

```
$out .=  '         <canvas id="myChart2" class="canpas chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; width: 454px; height: 300px;" width="454" height="300"></canvas>';
```

and this is my variable that i want to pass to my .js

```
         //result chart1
            @mssql_free_result($graph_query2);
            $dtDateChart1 = $dateTittleChart1;
            $convertChart1 = json_encode($datesChart1);
            $totalChart1 = json_encode($nMaxChart1);
            $labelChart1 =  $convertChart1;
```

i dont know how to pass it when i already succes getelementbyid thanks you if you know something about it that i should know. i dont have a lot knowledge about javascript passing variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make hidden input and put your php variable on its value then collect element value by js in your function 
I almost do this and it is working well

First in your code php or html 
Add input like

```
<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $dtDateChart1;  ?>'  id='dtDateChart1' >
```

chart.js

```
window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ['08:00'] , //Jamnya
                datasets: [{
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(85, 212, 226, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: '#55d4e2',
                    label: document.getElementById("dtDateChart1").value,
                    data: [600],
                    fill: true,
                    pointRadius: 5,
                    pointHoverRadius: 10,
                    showLine: true
                }]
            }, options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Total Online Today',
                    position: 'top',
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontStyle: 'bold'
                },
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                elements: {
                    point: {
                        pointStyle: 'circle'
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'TIME'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            major: {
                                fontStyle: 'bold',
                                fontColor: '#FF0000'
                            }
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'TOTAL ONLINE'
                        }
                    }]
                },
                tooltips:{
                    callbacks: {
                        title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                          return '<?php echo $dtDateChart1; ?>' +data['labels'][tooltipItem[0]['index']];
                        },
                        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                          return 'TOTAL : '+data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']]+'';
                        },
                    },
                    titleFontSize: 15,
                    bodyFontSize: 15,
                    displayColors: false
                }
            }
        }
     );

     return myChart;

}
```

Comment: i dont understand ,  so i make hidden in put in my variable ?

Comment: it work but when i pass some variable label. its not working

Comment: i mean variable labels not label

Comment: If you pass many values  you should use more input or pass them all encoded by json then decode them in js before use

Comment: yeah i use this

` echo '<input type="hidden" value="$dtDateChart1"  id="dtDateChart1">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" value="json_encode($datesChart1)"  id="labelChart1">';`

but in labelChart1 the value not show up when i passing to labels, but if i alert the value is show up

i dont know to say, i have already done this before with script i put in body but all page call that body and return variable isnt define yet except in my chart.php because i already defined it.

Comment: Iam sorry , it is not clear fot me but Basically you should know you cant include php code directly in js file but you can include it in inline js code

Comment: its working bro, but how to display 2 chart bro i nsame page? i already try but jsut one is display

Comment: I think you duplicate input with same id , you should make 2 inputs and give every one diff id like  <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $dtDateChart1;  ?>'  id='dtDateChart1' >     <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $dtDateChart2;  ?>'  id='dtDateChart2' >

Comment: i already define it bro
` "<input type='hidden' value='$dtDateChart1'  id='dtDateChart1'>";
            "<input type='hidden' value='$labelChart1'  id='labelChart1'>";
            "<input type='hidden' value='$totalChart1'  id='totalChart1'>";
             "<input type='hidden' value='$dtDateChart2'  id='dtDateChart2'>";
            "<input type='hidden' value='$labelChart2'  id='labelChart2'>";
            "<input type='hidden' value='$totalChart2'  id='totalChart2'>";`

but the pages show just one chart. 

i create 2 function for document.getElementByid chart 1, and chart2

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you cannot pass variables from php to javascript because they are different things and they are executed in different places.
your php code runs on your server and the javascript code in the client's browser so they are not seen.
what you can do is a php script that echos the content of the variable you want and through javascript and fetch or any library that makes requests to make a request to the php file

Answer (score 0):

You should not have php code inside js files.

What you can do instead is:

1. Inside the php file pass the values you need to js variables.
2. Then, use the global js variables or pass them as parameters to js functions.

Alternatively, instead of including the separate charts.js file, have the contents of charts.js in the php file inside a `<script>` tag. This way you can have php and js sideways as you did.

Comment: yeah before i do in my header, i create a function script. but in all page call that header too, and the problem i should define all the pages my variable that i define too in my chart.php